# Custom Sorting Of A Bound DataGridView

Tags: .net, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable. I have one column that's a pseudo-int -- you know the kind, where most of the time it has integers but sometimes instead there's an N/A. This column is a varchar, but I want to have it sort like an int column, treating the N/A as a -1.

The DataGridView provides for this -- *if* it's not bound to a DataTable. If it is bound, it uses the sorting mechanism of the bound object, and DataTables don't expose that functionality.

I can make a custom column in the DataTable with the behaviour I want, but because the DataGridView is bound to the DataTable, it sorts by the column it's displaying. I can make a custom column in the DataGridView, but I need to set the table to virtual mode to sort by that when I already have a solution that mostly works.

How do I make it sort my pseudo-int column as I want - where possible, sorting by int? This scenario seems like it's incredibly common, and I'm sure somewhere it's been provided for.

Answer (score 3):

When I've had to deal with sorting problems similar to this, my favorite method is to add a column to the DataTable and parse the pseudo-int into the sortable int that I want. Then in the DataGridView's binding you can simply hide that column of data, but because it's there you can still sort on it. It adds a little extra data to memory to do this, so depending on the performance hit and the size of your sorted data, this could be a potential issue. Also, anytime the data is modified, you'd need to make sure this extra column is kept in line.

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to a *DataView*, not a *DataTable*, e.g.:

```
private void SortByTwoColumns()
{
   DataView myDataView = DataTable1.DefaultView;
   myDataView.Sort = "State, ZipCode DESC";
   myGridView.DataSource = myDataView;
}
```

You have a few choices of dealing with the N/A data - *SELECT* statement, *RowPrePaint* event, and more.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem. It's already binding to the default view, and sorting by two columns will only last until the first time the user clicks a column header and sorts the table. The DataGridView *changes* the Sort property.

Comment: You can act on user clicks (catch events) and modify DataGridView behavior to suit you needs.

Comment: @Merus: Then disallow it. You could go through every column and set `SortMode` to `NotSortable`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change the SQL query to return this column as int (-1 for 'N/A') then use a custom formatter for the displayed column?

Comment: That's the approach Joel Etherton and I are taking in our answers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can adapt the code in my blog post to provide an IComparer specific to your int column:

http://adamhouldsworth.blogspot.com/2010/01/bound-datagridview-sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

Along with Joel Etherton's answer there's an event that you can handle that will let you override the displayed value for a cell.

So, like he said, you'll want two columns. One is a strongly-typed numeric column with -1s for the text values. The other is a hidden text column with the real values (mixed numerics and text values). As-is it will sort properly, but the user will see -1s instead of the actual value.

To fix this we need this code:

```
Private Sub dgDisplay_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
Handles dgDisplay.CellFormatting
    If Not (e.ColumnIndex = dgDisplay.Columns("NumericColumn").Index _
    AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then Exit Sub

    Dim newVal As String = dgDisplay.Item("ActualColumn", e.RowIndex).Value
    e.Value = newVal
End Sub
```

This will show the actual text value you want to see, even though the value in the bound `DataSource` is just a numeric.

If you're going to do any filtering on the `DataView` behind you `DataGridView`, make sure you filter on the hidden column.